# k8s scdf2 how config volumenMount in a task (no freetext)

Tags: kubernetes

Deploying a task, as user, i need config k8s params like i do using "freetext".

The k8s config is following

```
Secret: "kind": "Secret","apiVersion": "v1","metadata": {"name": "omni-secret","namespace": "default",
```

**bootstrap.yml:**

```
spring:
application:
name: mk-adobe-analytics-task
cloud:
kubernetes:
  config:
    enabled: false
  secrets:
    enabled: true
    namespace: default
    paths:
    - /etc/secret-volume


log.info(AdobeAnalyticsConstants.LOG_RECOVERING_SECRET, env.getProperty("aws.bucketname"));
```

Deploying task:

```
task launch test-007 --properties "deployer.*.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[{name: secret-volume, mountPath: '/etc/secret-volume'}], deployer.*  .kubernetes.volumes=[{name: 'secret-volume', secret: {secretName: 'omni-secret' }}]"
```

Result:

```
2019-06-10 10:32:50.852  INFO 1 --- Recovering property "aws.bucketname": null
```

How can i map into a task the k8s volumens?  simply k8s deploy , it is ok using streams

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear how to start with your issue but please take a look for [Kubernetes PropertySource implementations](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/2.1.0.RC1/multi/multi__kubernetes_propertysource_implementations.html).

Inside "**Secrets PropertySource - Table 3.2. Properties**" you can find other **settings** like:

```
- spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.name
- spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.labels
- spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enableApi
```

So please refer to the documentation.
It's also possible that your environment variable  **aws.bucketname** wasn't configured properly.
Hope this help.